# Predict classification probability of pretrained Random Forest in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I'm running examples of binary classification in Google Earth Engine with [ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-smilerandomforest), and I saving the models to apply them later using [ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-decisiontreeensemble). My objective is to get the classification probability, however I get only the discrete classification. I use the following code to save and load the models:

```
// Save the model

var trees = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(classifier.explain()).get('trees'))

var dummy = ee.Feature()        
var col = ee.FeatureCollection(trees.map(function(x){return dummy.set('tree',x)}))
Export.table.toAsset(col,'save_classifier',AssetName)

// Load classifier

var trees = ee.FeatureCollection(AssetName).aggregate_array('tree')

var classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble(trees).setOutputMode('PROBABILITY')
```

Is there any method to get the probability values instead of the discrete classification?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like probability mode isn't working there.  Use "raw" and compute the probability yourself.  In pseudo-code:

```
classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble().setOutputMode("raw")
result = image.classify(classifier)
max = result.array_reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())
prob = result.eq(max).array_reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

Note, you can use mean to compute probability because after the `eq()`, it's all 1s and 0s and mean = sum/count = count(1s)/count(all)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used directly: prob = result.arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), ee.List([0])) and then transform to Image using ArrayProject and ArrayFlatten  , which give exactly the probability, I believe, right?

Comment: @aminkh `prob = result.arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), ee.List([0])).arrayGet(0)` seems to work